# Write LookAt Matrix For Unity Manually

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, matrix, vector

I was writing my own Matrix4x4 and Quaternion classes in Unity with using C#. These classes are required for my game and these are using Fixed Point Math. Also i wrote "Test Class" for comparing and testing class values with Unity's self Quaternion and Matrix classes.

**IsSame Method**: Compares my Matrix4x4 class and Unity's Matrix4x4 class, if they are same (with tolerans value) returns true else false

```
bool isSame(Matrix4x4 a, Matrix4x4F b)
{
  float t = 0.001f;
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    if (Mathf.Abs(a[i] - (float) b[i]) > t)
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

**Show Method**: Types values to debug screen.

```
void show(Matrix4x4 a, Matrix4x4F b, String textName)
{
   Debug.Log($"{isSame(a, b)}\n{a} \n{b}" + textName);
}
```

**MatrixMethodTest**: Just calling show method, using dummy numbers.

```
 show(
Matrix4x4.LookAt(new Vector3(3,5,1), new Vector3(76,34,11), new Vector3(10.4323f,13.4343f,2.4398f)), 
Matrix4x4F.LookAt(new Vector3F(3,5,1), new Vector3F(76,34,11), new Vector3F(10.4323m,13.4343m,2.4398m)), " LOOK AT");
```

But when i try to implement LookAt method for my game, test class that i wrote is giving me an error and it returns false.
[Comparing Matrix Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtAdZ.png)

I tried to calculate LookAt method using TRS.

```
public static Matrix4x4F LookAt(Vector3F from, Vector3F to, Vector3F up)
{
    return TRS(Vector3F.zero, QuaternionF.LookRotation((to - from).normalized, up.normalized), Vector3F.one);
}
```

Here is my TRS Method, it referances to Matrix4x4F LookAt

```
public static Matrix4x4F TRS(Vector3F pos, QuaternionF q, Vector3F s)
{
      Matrix4x4F tr = Matrix4x4F.Translate(pos);
      Matrix4x4F ro = Matrix4x4F.Rotate(q);
      Matrix4x4F sc = Matrix4x4F.Scale(s); 

      return tr * ro * sc;
}
```

I thought the reason could be, QuaternionF.LookRotaion method and I also check my Quaternion LookRotation Class.

```
public static QuaternionF LookRotation(Vector3F forward, Vector3F up)
  {
    if(up == forward) {
      up.Normalize();
      Vector3F v = forward + up * -Vector3F.Dot(up, forward);
      QuaternionF q = QuaternionF.FromToRotation(Vector3F.forward, v);
      return QuaternionF.FromToRotation(v, forward) * q;
    }
    else {
      return QuaternionF.FromToRotation(Vector3F.forward, forward);
    }
}
```

What am I missing? Besides where can i find Unity's Matrix LookAt functions?

**

- MY TRS: [TRS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIEZX.png)
- MY TRANSLATE: [Translate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icdBk.png)
- MY FROM TO ROTATION: [From To Rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69C1K.png)

**

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Paste the code in your question so we can read it easily.

Comment: As far as I know Unity's Matrix, Quaternion etc functions are part of the C++ engine that's closed. And I suspect them to have optimized those core parts of the engine. Why would you implement them yourself? C# code won't be able to match the engine's performance I think.

Comment: As i mentioned top of this entry, i must use Fixed Point Math in game. And I'm trying to implement Fixed Point Math functions to my Quaternion, Vector and Matrix classes @frankhermes. Well, if you know any sample classes about it you can share with me.

Comment: I would really, really, strongly, really strongly urge you to not try to write your own math. For one I don't think you actually need to, despite whatever use case you may have, and for two you're going to wind up converting your fixed-point math to floating-point math anyways because that's how you're going to position and orient your things in Unity. That said, you're jumping right to the end here and trying to debug `LookRotation` when you have a ton of intermediate things you could verify first - `Matrix4x4F.Translate`, etc., `TRS`, and `FromToRotation`. Have you verified those outputs?

Comment: Hey There @Chuck, i added values bottom of the my text. Check Them! Yea, i verified them and they are working correctly!

Comment: @MertBalkan some of your numbers in the to from rotation are off by more than 30 percent, so I don't know how or why you're accepting them as correct.

Comment: @Chuck I added tolerance number for that, yea It's not a problem for now.

Comment: You say it's not a problem, but it's off by 30% and it's being used directly in your calculation for `LookRotation`. Then you're here saying that your `LookRotation` values are not correct.

Comment: I didn't mean that, still the numbers are not correct in this situation. I think my calculation is not correct. Tolerance was just for testing the values even they are nearly same. But the main problem is: values that calculated behind, they are not even close to Unity's values.